# yarn install doesn’t fetch update from library repo

Tags: react-native, yarnpkg

was facing this issue in my React native project

Issue: 
1. Have two repos -

a. Main React Native App GitHub repo

b. Library repo - Example - https://github.com/testlib

2. Main React native App repo uses library repo as a package.
   So, added an entry in package.json

   Example -

   "devDependencies": {
                “test-lib”: “testlib”
      }

Then I did yarn install. Everything worked fine. Saw the testily repo changes add as package in **/node_modules**.

Further, I updated the **testlib** repo with some changes and thought that if I do **yarn install** again in my main app repo will give me the latest changes within my main app.

But, found that the updated changes were not included in my main repo **/node_modules**

Answer (score 5):

If your `package.json` dependency for `test-lib` points to a git repository and not to some sort of tag definition (as @udai describes) then a regular `yarn install` [will not look for changes to the git repository as based on the lock file, that dependency is satisfied](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3348).

What you can do as an alternative to tagging (useful if you are actively developing the module and are not at a point where tagging is appropriate) is either use:

- `yarn upgrade` - This will upgrade all dependencies though.
- `yarn upgrade test-lib` - This should upgrade just your `test-lib` [based on what the docs say](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/).
- `yarn add <git-repo path/url>` - This will install the latest version of that module ([see docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/)). Use this instead of `yarn add test-lib` since I assume that your package isn't published yet (or that your changes aren't publicly published yet).

I suggest reading through the yarn docs to familiarize yourself with what they actually do by default.

Comment: I have searched for months for an explanation to this problem. Finally stumbled onto one!

Comment: command `yarn upgrade xxx` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

I created release tags for each update which I wanted my main App to include.
So, I created **2 release tags** - **v1.0.0** for first commit and then **v1.0.1** for the update which I wanted to include later in my main repo.

Since, tags has been added for new updates, I had to do some small changes in my main App repo **package.json** file.

“**test-lib**”: “**testlib**”

**REPLACED to:**

“**test-lib**”: “**testlib#v1.0.1**”,